как узнать что указатели на базовые классы указывают на один объект
как узнать что указатели pA и pB указывают на один и тот же объект?
class baseA
{/*тут поля, функции и т.п*/};

class baseB
{/*тут поля, функции и т.п*/};

class myClass : public baseA, public baseB
{/*тут поля, функции и т.п*/};

int main()
{

    myClass obj;

    baseA* pA = &obj;
    baseB* pB = &obj;

    if(pA == pB)
       // а как

    return 0;
}

возможные идеи:

pA + sizeof(baseB) == pB или что то вроде, но как компилятор сделает непонятна: + или -
никак
изначально идея херня


Надо взять смещения каких-либо public полей в baseA и baseB от начала  myClass и посмотреть, получится ли один и тот же адрес объекта вычисленный по pA и pB

static_cast<myClass *>(pA) == static_cast<myClass *>(pB)

@user7860670 действительно хорошая идея
